# Listen for Back key events fired when TableView is in focus

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` in my JavaFX application and I would like to listen for user key presses when the `TableView` is in focus. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using JavaFX 1 or 2?

Comment: It's JavaFX 2. I thought everybody uses JFX2 these days.

Comment: For new projects, I would strongly recommend using JavaFX 8.

Comment: That's the version that we are using. I thought people usually refer to JavaFX 2+ (including JavaFX 8) as JavaFX 2.

Comment: @SandahAung They /just/ changed the naming convention to match the JavaFX version with the regular Java version. I think it's correct to now say JavaFX 8. I generally just make a strong distinction between JavaFX 1 and JavaFX 2 when they dropped support for the JavaFX scripting language. So when you said JavaFX 2 that sounded like a reasonable answer to me :*)

Comment: Th guess they were doing this for marketing purposes. Btw, thanks for your answer. You've solved a great headache of mine.

Comment: If you're using Java[FX] 8 you can drop a lot of the verbosity in the code. @Jazzepi 's answer becomes two lines (including the comment). Perhaps more importantly, a lot of fairly large bugs in JavaFX were fixed in that release.

Comment: James if you want to post an example I can include it in the answer, or you can post your own :)

Comment: If you are talking about lambdas, I agree. And a good thing they fixed they bugs in JFX 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to take your TableView object and attach an EventHandler to using one of the .setOnKeyPressed, .setOnKeyReleased, or setOnKeyTyped methods.

So something like this.

```
tableViewObject.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
        //Put your awesome application specific logic here
    }
});
```

According to the docs for key events the target is the element that has focus, so your key event listener will only fire when the tableView or one of it's children nodes has focus on the key press.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm

*Target Selection
When an action occurs, the system determines which node is the target based on internal rules:
For key events, the target is the node that has focus.*